# Why the list doesn't iterate till end and pops all the items out in python

Tags: python, list, stack

I want that `for` loop iterates the number of times, there are `items` in `my_list`, and correspondingly during each execution `pops` the `items` out of `my_list` and add them in `purchase_list`, until all the elements of `my_list` are popped and appended into the `purchase_list`. **But** it doesn't happen. Why?

```
my_list = ['pen' , 'pencil' , 'cell phone' , 'axiom team' , 'panacloud' ]
purchase_list = []
for items in my_list:
    purchase_item = my_list.pop()
    purchase_list.append(purchase_item)

print(purchase_list)
```

Output is as follows:

```
['panacloud', 'axiom team', 'cell phone']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: @MooingRawr Please read my clarification in "Edit"

Comment: and the duplicate link does have some answers that explain why. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34238688/4099813 Also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is why your code is not working. Well popping the element is never a good idea in Python during the iteration. While iterating and popping you are actually iterating from the front while removing(shrinking) your list(from rear) in the same loop. That is the reason loop executed three times as other elements were removed with earlier two iterations.

Why not just reversing the list and creating a new list ?

```
new_list = list(reversed(my_list))
```

If you want your new_list to be emptied

```
new_list =[]
```

OR if you want to delete

```
del my_list
```

Comment: perfect explanation! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do not `pop` while iterating through list.

If you are looking to empty one list and fill another, use:

```
my_list = ['pen' , 'pencil' , 'cell phone' , 'axiom team' , 'panacloud' ]

purchase_list = my_list  # ['pen', 'pencil', 'cell phone', 'axiom team', 'panacloud']
my_list = []             # []
```